# Roles assignement in Hyperledger Indy

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-indy

How are the roles assigned to the nodes in hyperledger indy , is it configured through a file or by some other proceedure ? And are the roles assigned to nodes or agents ?

I read the documentation of the hyperleder indy but didn't find anything related to this

Answer (score 0):

1. In Hyperledger Indy `roles` are assigned to `agents` rather than nodes. `Agents` however are implemented in hard coding (Python, Go, JS) which interact with the ledger.

   - As an example in application built on top of Indy there could be defined following roles: `Steward`, `Trustee`, or `Endorser` and assign permissions to each role.
   - Following example is the small part from one of my projects, where `AnchorHandle` class serves as a wrapper for interacting with ledger using Indy SDK, and there I used `INDY_ROLE_TYPES` to map specific role ID to role names in Indy environment:

     ```
     INDY_ROLE_TYPES = {
             "0": "TRUSTEE",
             "2": "STEWARD",
             "100": "TGB",
             "101": "TRUST_ANCHOR",
           }
     ```
   - And in the following example which is the part of web server to interact with Indy ledger role information is retrieved from a transaction data and converts the role ID into role name:

     ```
     role = data.get('role')
     if role != None:
     role_name = INDY_ROLE_TYPES.get(role, role)
     text.append("ROLE: " + role_name)
     ```
2. And to learn how the Indy environment works and how to assign roles you can follow these:

   - [In the following link](https://hyperledger-indy.readthedocs.io/projects/node/en/latest/auth_rules.html?highlight=role#default-auth-map-rules) - you will find `Default AUTH_MAP Rules` where you can check description for each of them.
   - [Sovrin Glossary](https://sovrin.org/wp-content/uploads/Sovrin-Glossary-V2.pdf) - which helps to understand the meaning of the terms
   - [Indy official documentation](https://hyperledger-indy.readthedocs.io/projects/node/en/latest/toc.html) - you have to read and analyze each part for better understanding and interacting with Indy SDK
   - [Regional-Communities](https://www.hyperledger.org/participate/regional-communities) - lastly, here you can find regional communities, where you can also get experienced level help.

Answer (score 0):

Indy is a permissioned network, therefore each node is identified by a bls key. To add a node to a network then an agent needs to send a transaction(includes the public key and node ip) to add that node to the existing network. That transaction needs to be signed usually by an agent that controls a did key(ed25519) who has the role of trustee, steward (it depends actually on the auth map rules) on the network.